# Entry in cron.d not executed

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

I have a cron task configured in cron.d directory that would get executed for every 5 minutes. The entry is

```
*/5  *  *  *  *   root   /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/test_consolelog
```

This would invoke the logrotate. However the logrotate didn't happen. I checked the /var/log/cron file to see if cron executes the command and could see that the command is getting executed for every 5 minutes.

I tried executing the command mannually on the terminal and could see that the command is executed and log rotation happens.

What could be reason that logrotate is not happening when getting executed from cron.d.

Regars,
Bala

Comment: That may depend on test_consolelog logrotate configuration (like it does not rotate becuase you just tried manually and no condition triggers the rotation), pls add it to the question; or, if you want to always force logrotate to run even if conditions are not met, use option `-f`

Comment: Sorry to miss it. I have configured the logrotate to rotate when ever the size of the file exceeds 20Mb. When the cron task executes i checked the size of file to be more than 35 Mb. Still the logrotation failed. When i trigger the same manually, rotation was successfull. The entry in logrotate config file is /var/test/testagent/logs/*.log {
nocompress
copytruncate
notifempty
missingok
rotate 50
size 20M
}

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? Did you get any error, or just did not happen? Anyway, try changing the cron command to `*/5  *  *  *  *   root   /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/test_consolelog` and see what happens

Comment: The main problem here is i didn't find any errors :(. Just it did not happen. Anyway i am trying -f option.

Comment: Failed now too. How ever in /var/log/cron i could see the error msg "(CRON) bad minute (/etc/cron.d/logrotate)"

Comment: Then that is the error, isn't it?

Comment: */5  *  *  *  *   root   /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/test_consolelog is the entry in /etc/cron.d/logrotate file. Would be helpful if the error is pointed out..

Comment: Looks like you have a primitive cron which doesn't recognize the slash notation. Try with writing it out in longhand 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55

Comment: Tried 5 instead of */5 and failed in that too

Comment: I suspect it is problem with my logrotate.. I am investigating in that direction

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. The SELinux needs to be disabled for this to work. Earlier while testing the sestatus value is disabled in the the /etc/selinux/config file however the current status was enforcing. Once i restarted the vm itself the sestatus updated to disabled and logrotate functioned as desired. prior to that i have fixed the bad minute error too.

I had furnished enough details for this post and done enough research before posting here. However i am not sure why some one marked this post as there is no research effort or unclear or unuseful...